# how to add extra vspace in TOC after one specific section?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I like some extra vertical white space in the TOC after one specific section.

So far I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\preto\section{% 
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip10pt}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{No extra space in TOC 1}
\section{No extra space in TOC 2}
\section{Chapter after which extra space in TOC is wanted}
\section{No extra space in TOC 3}

\end{document}
```

This does create extra space the way I want it, but after *all* chapters.
(by the way I tried different things and I'm not sure if both packages are needed for the thing I have now...)

How can I specify one chapter that the extra space should be put after in the TOC?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `\addtocontents`

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{No extra space in TOC 1}
\section{No extra space in TOC 2}
\section{Chapter after which extra space in TOC is wanted}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
\section{No extra space in TOC 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]